# Why MySQL WorkBench is ignoring my SIGNAL SQLSTATE when using cursors?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

First of all, the code is a bit messy, but I can't help it for the assignment. Back to the problem, I'm trying to stop an insert if aux < nDragonesNecesarios, but in the entire code, when I write `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';` it does not work. Even if I put it before anything else, it treats it as if there is nothing. I've checked the code, and it seems to be executing completely (it doesn't exit the cursor and it enters in all the if's), everything is executing perfectly except the SIGNAL SQLSTATE.

I've been searching but I did not find anything about the SIGNAL SQLSTATE not working if it is used with cursors. But every time I declare a cursor in a trigger (even if I don't use it) it ignores my SIGNAL SQLSTATE. Is there any sintaxis stuff that I'm missing?

This is the trigger that I had to do for an assignment:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER check_if_unlocked BEFORE INSERT ON mata
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
    DECLARE nDragonesNecesarios INT; #El numero de dragones necesarios a matar para poder matar al siguiente
    DECLARE nombrePersonajeAux VARCHAR(250);
    DECLARE aux INT; #albergará el numero de dragones que ha matado un personaje
    DECLARE curMagos CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT DISTINCT magoCompone.nombreMago
            FROM magoCompone
            WHERE magoCompone.idEscuadron = NEW.idEscuadron;
    DECLARE curGuerreros CURSOR FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT guerreroCompone.nombreGuerrero
            FROM guerreroCompone
            WHERE guerreroCompone.idEscuadron = NEW.idEscuadron;
    DECLARE curTanques CURSOR FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT tanqueCompone.nombreTanque
            FROM tanqueCompone
            WHERE tanqueCompone.idEscuadron = NEW.idEscuadron;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    SET nDragonesNecesarios = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM dragon
                                WHERE dragon.vida < (SELECT dragon.vida
                                                    FROM dragon
                                                    WHERE dragon.nombreDragonDesbloqueador = NEW.nombreDragon));
    
    
    #Recorro los magos que pertenezcan al escuadrón
    OPEN curMagos;
    read_loop_mago: LOOP
    FETCH curMagos INTO nombrePersonajeAux;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop_mago;
    END IF;
    
    SET aux = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM magoCompone inner join mata on magoCompone.idEscuadron = mata.idEscuadron
                WHERE magoCompone.nombreMago = nombrePersonajeAux);
                
    IF aux < nDragonesNecesarios THEN # Ha matado a menos dragones de los necesarios
        SET done = true;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curMagos;
    
    SET done = FALSE;
    #Recorro los guerreros que pertenezcan al escuadrón    
    OPEN curGuerreros;
    read_loop_guerrero: LOOP
    FETCH curGuerreros INTO nombrePersonajeAux;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop_guerrero;
    END IF;
    
    SET aux = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM guerreroCompone inner join mata on guerreroCompone.idEscuadron = mata.idEscuadron
                WHERE guerreroCompone.nombreGuerrero = nombrePersonajeAux);
                
    IF aux < nDragonesNecesarios THEN # Ha matado a menos dragones de los necesarios
        SET done = true;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curGuerreros;
    
    SET done = FALSE;            
    #Recorro los tanques que pertenezcan al escuadrón    
    OPEN curTanques;
    read_loop_tanque: LOOP
    FETCH curTanques INTO nombrePersonajeAux;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop_tanque;
    END IF;
    
    SET aux = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM tanqueCompone inner join mata on tanqueCompone.idEscuadron = mata.idEscuadron
                WHERE tanqueCompone.nombreTanque = nombrePersonajeAux);
                
    IF aux < nDragonesNecesarios THEN # Ha matado a menos dragones de los necesarios
        SET done = true;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curTanques;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need do Declare an exit handler like here in the shortened example

```
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' 
  BEGIN SET @a := 23; 
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
 
  END;
```

> ```
> CREATE Table A ( A1 int , A2 int);
> INSERT INTO A VALUES( 5,2),(7,1);
>
> CREATE Table B ( B1 int, B2 int, B3 int, B4 int, B5 int, B6 int);
> INSERT INTO B VALUES(5,4,6,1,2,0)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER abdtrg  Before INSERT ON A
> FOr EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
>  DECLARE nombrePersonajeAux INTEGER;
>  DECLARE nombrePersonajeAux2 INTEGER;
>  DECLARE curMagos CURSOR FOR SELECT A1,A2 FROM A;
>  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
>  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' 
>  BEGIN SET @a := 23; 
>          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
>         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
>
>  END;
>      OPEN curMagos;
>     read_loop_mago: LOOP
>         FETCH curMagos INTO nombrePersonajeAux,nombrePersonajeAux2;
>         SET @a := -1;
>     IF done THEN
>         LEAVE read_loop_mago;
>     END IF;
>         IF nombrePersonajeAux  > nombrePersonajeAux2 THEN # Ha matado a menos dragones de los necesarios
>         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000'
>         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón';
>         SET done := true;
>         LEAVE read_loop_mago;
>     END IF;
>     END LOOP read_loop_mago;
>     CLOSE curMagos;
>   END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,1)
> ```
>
> ```
> Error: Algún integrante del escuadrón no tiene desbloqueados los dragones necesarios para matar a este dragón
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *,@a FROM A
> ```
>
> ```
> A1 | A2 | @a
> -: | -: | -:
>  5 |  2 | 23
>  7 |  1 | 23
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65f94e784f5223c7699ca1a4e68ebf70)*

Comment: Hi, the signal sqlstate now works, but it doesn't let me insert anything in the table now, the error is always popping up even if the condition is false

Comment: You ask how can i do it, i told you so, what you want id debugging, and that you have to do yourself. if you want make a dbfiddle with the behaviour and i can look at it.